# How to extract kotlin-react html into a method

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

I'd like to create a method containing an "html" snippet but I get the error below.

```
import react.dom.a
import react.dom.button
import react.dom.div
import react.dom.nav
import react.dom.span
import kotlinx.html.ButtonType
import react.RBuilder
import react.RComponent
import react.RProps
import react.RState

class App : RComponent<RProps, RState>() {

    override fun RBuilder.render() {

        div("container fill") {
        }
        div {
            content()
        }
    }

    fun content() {
        return div() { } // the error below is for this line
    }
}
```

> error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is
>   applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public inline fun
>   RBuilder.div(classes: String? = ..., block: RDOMBuilder.() ->
>   Unit): ReactElement defined in react.dom
>           return div() {

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the receiver, and probably get rid of `return` like this:

```
class App : RComponent<RProps, RState>() {

    override fun RBuilder.render() {

        div("container fill") {
        }
        div {
            content()
        }
    }

    fun RBuilder.content() {
        div() { }
    }
}
```